# How to execute a unit test found in an in-memory assembly using xUnit in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I am trying to run found xUnit tests in C# code (not Test Explorer!). The idea is to create an application that can test C# code input of users. For example the user needs to type the code to throw an exception. Instead of me checking it manually I want the application to test if the user has entered to correct code. Since the user can create his/her own variables I can't check if the code is the same with my idea of the solution.

This is what I have so far:

1. I grab the code of the user and add a unit test to it. Then combine both so it's one codebase. I then create an assembly of it by using CSharpCompilation. This works fine. I test if it works with unit tests (yes, the irony of testing unit tests programmably with unit tests...).

This is how I concatenate both pieces of code:

```
string codeExample = @"
    using System;
    using Xunit;

    namespace RoslynCompileSample
    {
        public class Writer
        {
            public void Write(string message)
            {
                throw new Exception(""This is correct"");
            }
        }
    }";

string codeUnitTest = @"
    namespace RoslynCompileTestSample
    {
        public class LearningPathTests
        {
            [Fact]
            public void Should_ResultInBadValidation()
            {
                RoslynCompileSample.Writer rcs = new();
                Assert.True(1 == 1);
            }
        }
    }";

string codeFile = codeExample + Environment.NewLine + codeUnitTest;
```

So imagine the throwing of the exception is what a user has entered. Then I use the codeFile contents to create the assembly.

2. Then I search for all the unit tests of said assembly. I get one result back. I do this with the following code:

```
string nameTestClass = "Write";

var testMethods = assembly.GetTypes()
                .Single(x => x.Name == nameTestClass).GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes()
                    .Any(a => a.GetType().Name.Contains("Fact")))
                .ToList();
```

But now I am stuck

I can't seem to figure out how to run the found unit test in C# code. I did found a few options:

1. I tried the [AssemblyRunner](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.runner.utility/Runners/AssemblyRunner.cs) would work. But that requires a dll or exe, which I don't have an don't want.
2. Then I found some information about the [XunitFrontController](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/542). But this one needs a real dll or exe too.

But I don't have a dll or exe file. I have an Assembly in memory and I don't want to write a file to the disk of the server/machine/whatever it will run on.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Running into the same problem. Did you find an answer somewhere?